# Print out the strings that are >= a threshold using a foreach loop?

Tags: java, string, foreach, filter

```
public Set<String> filterAlleles (int threshold) {
    Set<String> filtered = new HashSet<String>();
    Map<String, Integer> counted = this.countAlleles();
    for (String allele : _alleles){
```

I previously wrote the countAlleles method, so I am using it in this method declaration as instructed to. The countAlleles method returns the Allele and the number of times it occurred.

Comment: This should also be tagged with the programming language name.

Comment: iterate the `counted` map and remove entries with a value less than the threshold (using an `Iterator` on the `#entrySet`), then print map

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code using a for loop that will filter the data for >= 7 and print them.  Since you provided very little of the code, I'll attach the example that will hopefully help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Integer> counted = new HashMap<>();
    counted.put("foo", 3);
    counted.put("bar", 10);
    counted.put("baz", 6);
    counted.put("goo", 11);

    counted.entrySet().stream()                // Stream the entry set
            .filter(e->e.getValue() >= 7)      // Filter on >= threshold
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)            // Get the key since it's the name we are looking for
            .forEach(System.out::println);     // Print the list
}
```

Comment: What's the point of collecting it to a list? It's like a no-op in this case.

Comment: In case they wanted do operate further on the strings, but otherwise the collect can be left out.  It's an example, since the question provided so little information.